# Spurious wakeups in Java's BlockingQueue.take()

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I wrote this code where I trap `InterruptedException`'s in a blocking queue and try again to consume from the same queue thinking of spurious wakeups. I don't know if in this case I should be thinking of spurious wakeups since I am not calling `wait()` directly.

Basically, the worry that someone raised is that if the `take` throws an `InterruptedException`, I should stop processing (so the `while` should be inside the `try`, the opposite of what I did). There is already a mechanism to stop processing by calling a public method in the class, but I don't know if processing should also be stopped by an `InterruptedException`.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

```
private BlockingQueue<MyMessage> queue;
...
@Override
public void run() {
   log.debug("[run] Starting processing");

   while (runningController.isRunning()) {
      try {
         MyMessage message = queue.take(); // will block if empty

         assert message != null; // a blocking queue can never return null

         RuntimeMessage parsedMsg = processMessage(message);

         if (parsedMsg != null) {
            outputConsumer.messageArrived(parsedMsg);
         } else {
            log.warn("[run] Unparsed message 0x" + Integer.toHexString(message.getCommandType()));
         }

      } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
         log.error("[run] Interrupted while reading from queue", exc);
      } catch (MessageConfigurationException exc) {
         log.error("[run] Error finding structure configuration for received message", exc);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write, that message **cannot** be `null`, why are you asserting for it then?
That code is IMO noise. I'd rather remove it. Other than that, the comment on it is even more noisy. Your assert says exactly what your comment says. Why keep it?

Same should go for the `//will block if empty`. It's noise, as it adds no value to the understanding of the code. It's clear that `BlockingQueue.take()` **will** block when there's no messages, why would there be a need to write a comment on that?

Currently you catch inside your while loop. this means your execution continues, even when `InterruptedException` or `MessageConfigurationException` is thrown. You should keep that, given the case it is desired behavior. You have to decide on a case to case basis. We miss the context to decide on that, that's why its **your** job, isn't it ;)

If you want to stop execution when you caught an exception, just call that public method you mentioned. It's not like calls from other public members are forbidden ;)

Oh and a minor nitpick, the name for your `BlockingQueue` could be better, I'd probably go for `messages`.

Comment: i know the execution continues, the question is if that makes sense. If say, an InterruptedException has the intent of terminating a thread then I should not ignore it and continue processing in the thread, but that's what i don't know. The javadoc says "InterruptedException - if interrupted while waiting" but i don't know if I can just ignore it and try taking again or I should terminate ASAP. My reasoning was that because of spurious wakeups it was ok to ignore it. Someone else in my team disagrees and thinks I should kill the thread ASAP after an InterruptedException

Comment: @Hilikus As I said in my answer, I don't have enough context to judge that. Personally, I *guess* you should keep executing.

Comment: ok, if the answer is open to context then i guess it is not automatically wrong to ignore a InterruptedException, that partially answers my question

Comment: "Interruption is usually the most sensible way to implement interruption". (Brian Goetz: Java Concurrency in Practice, 2006).